# Decipher unknown Visual FoxPro memo field data to image file

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to extract a vfp table into mysql. The database I am trying to make use of in my own app is from an obsolete delphi app which has long been dropped out of the market.

My problem is that the vfp table contains a memo field which is probably some sort of image file, or some sort of zipped file; I am able to extract the memo data out of the vfp table by ***select image from word1.dbf where no=1*** && ***strtofile(image, '1.jpg')***; but the file '1.jpg' extracted doesn't seem to be a valid jpg file. And the way how the images are written into the memo field is unknown to me.

My question is, based on the above mentioned situation, is it possible to decipher the memo data and reconstruct image files out of it? How?

Comment: Do you have a copy of Visual Foxpro to determine what exactly is in the memo field, and if not, how do you know for sure they are images? Memo fields are often used for large amounts of text that won't fit in a standard text field.

Comment: Herb, I replicated 100 entries into a word1.dbf/word1.fpt file, and converted 5 files from the memo: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-InjWN32CvTV3dSdnlnX3V2VlU I am not sure if this memo only contains image, maybe it contains more info; but at least the image is stored in it (the field name is 'Image', and the app is similar to a chinese font dictionary, it looks http://chinese-calligraphy-dictionary.wikichina.com/ has a same db)

Comment: Not sure what the files/data are.  Looking at one of them I see a lot of repeating patterns like "0F C9 FF C1 E0 CD 00 3F C4 FF C1 F8 E6 00 0F C9".  I don't think you have a VFP problem, it's more like a binary file identification problem...